# How to scale the x and y-axis after update, configure, and refresh the ILLinePlot?

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

If update the line plot in ILPanel1 from the other function and the x & y-axis display range becomes too small, how can scale the x and y-axis at the other ILPanel1?  For example, the following code:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ILPanel1.GetCurrentScene().First<ILLinePlot>().Update(arrayData);
        ILPanel1.Scene.Configure();
        ILPanel1.Refresh();
    }
```

I realize you can move your mouse to the area of ILPanel1 and scroll it with you mouse to zoom-in and out, but anyone can tell me how to do that in the code level?

Answer (score 0):

Method GetCurrentScene() returns the **copy** of the current scene. The subsequent code does not affect any changes to the scene. Use the following code to get the direct access and to change the scene:

```
ILPanel1.Scene.First<ILLinePlot>().Update(arrayData);
ILPanel1.Scene.Configure();
ILPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>().Reset();
ILPanel1.Refresh();
```

Comment: Can I set the scale like xlim([1 10]); or ylim([-2 2]); in matlab.

Comment: Can I set the scale like xlim([0 10]) or ylim([-2 2]) in Matlab?